# flutter package return jcenter 403 Forbidden

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I added the SMS library in the Flutter but after compile flutter returns this error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':sms'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sms:classpath'.
       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
         Required by:
             project :sms
          > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
             > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
    > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sms' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 3s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What can I do in this situation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check your internet ? while running it.

Comment: its connected and i use proxy too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sina you are connecting from iran and we are banned by google... use a VPN... i recommend proton

Comment: I used it, but apparently the site is also closed with a proxy

Comment: change your VPN your problem is something normal right now